# Set and Get Object with multiple .on() methods using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, set

I have the process:

1. User clicks item (Postee object is SET)
2. User clicks post (Postee object is GET and used to submit)

My code looks like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var postee;

    //SHARE FEED ITEM START
    $(document).on('click', '.feed-item-share', function(e){

        var $this = $(this);
        var feed_item = $this.closest('.feed-item');

        var postee = {
            object_id : feed_item.attr('data-feed-item-object-id'),
            type : feed_item.attr('data-feed-item-type'),
            user_id : feed_item.attr('data-feed-item-user-id'),
            id : feed_item.attr('data-feed-item-postee-id'),
            name : feed_item.attr('data-feed-item-postee-name'),
            img_id : feed_item.attr('data-feed-item-postee-img-id')
        }

        console.log("Postee: "+postee);
    });

    $('#share_post_button').on('click', function (e) {

        console.log(postee);

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Post Click');
    });
});
```

Does anyone know why I cannot GET the `postee` object when I click `#share_post_button`? The console log comes back with an undefined variable error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Scope` of `postee` is not accessible in `share_post_button` click handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you redefine the `postee` variable within your `.feed-item-share` click handler, so it's out of scope of the `#share_post_button` click handler. Remove the `var`. Also note that you should use `data()` to retrieve `data-*` attributes, as it is read from jQuery's internal cache and saves DOM reads.

Try this:

```
postee = {
    object_id : feed_item.data('feed-item-object-id'),
    type : feed_item.data('feed-item-type'),
    user_id : feed_item.data('feed-item-user-id'),
    id : feed_item.data('feed-item-postee-id'),
    name : feed_item.data('feed-item-postee-name'),
    img_id : feed_item.data('feed-item-postee-img-id')
}
```

Comment: Bad Idea, when `share_post_button` is clicked before `.feed-item-share`

Comment: It won't error, but the properties of the object will be undefined. I would hope the OP has server-side validation in place (at least) for that scenario.

Comment: Or, you can get the values from `DOM` in both the event handlers. No need of *global* variables

Comment: @Tushar `#share_post_button` can only be clicked after `.feed-item-share`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this solution works! Thanks for answering & commenting!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.